# How to split a string without using array data structures?

Tags: java, string, loops, split

Say I have the String, "525.005"

I want to be able to set variable references for the numbers before the decimal (525) and after the decimal (005), however I'm **NOT allowed to use arrays**. String methods are allowed and indeces. I've seen other questions, and all of them suggest using arrays. Is there a way using a loop?

```
before = "525"
after = "005"
```

Comment: This is obviously homework. We are discouraged from answering homework questions that show no effort to solve on your own. Try this out, if you get stuck let us know exactly where. Hint: check out the `String.charAt()` function.

Comment: Use a loop to go through the string to find the position of the decimal. Then you can use `String.substring()` to get the different parts.

Comment: predec = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("."));  I found out you can use indexOf(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse it to a double.

Modulo your double by 1.0 to get the decimal value, subtract that from original value to get interger part.

String myString="525.005";

double StringAsDouble=parseDouble(myString);

double decimalPart=StringAsDouble % 1.0;
double integerPart=StringAsDouble - decimalPart;